# How to change camera source with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, navigator, mediadevices

I have a task to display a web camera through a website with some code like this:

```js
feather.replace();

const controls = document.querySelector('.controls');
const cameraOptions = document.querySelector('.video-options>select');
const video = document.querySelector('video');
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const screenshotImage = document.querySelector('img');
const buttons = [...controls.querySelectorAll('button')];
let streamStarted = false;
const [play, pause, screenshot] = buttons;

const constraints = {
    video: {
        width: {
            min: 1280,
            ideal: 1920,
            max: 2560,
        },
        height: {
            min: 720,
            ideal: 1080,
            max: 1440
        },
    }
}

const getCameraSelection = () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {
        const videoDevices = devices.filter(device => device.kind === 'videoinput');
        const options = videoDevices.map(videoDevice => {
            return `<option value="${videoDevice.deviceId}">${videoDevice.label}</option>`;
        });
        cameraOptions.innerHTML = options.join('');
    });
}

const startStream = (constraints, changeMode = false) => {
    try {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream) => {
            if (!changeMode) getCameraSelection();
            video.srcObject = stream;
            console.log('video.srcObject :', video.srcObject);
            video.play();
            play.classList.add('d-none');
            pause.classList.remove('d-none');
            screenshot.classList.remove('d-none');
            streamStarted = true;
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

play.onclick = () => {
    if (streamStarted) {
        video.play();
        play.classList.add('d-none');
        pause.classList.remove('d-none');
        return;
    }
    if ('mediaDevices' in navigator) {
        const updatedConstraints = {
            ...constraints,
            deviceId: {
                exact: cameraOptions.value
            }
        };
        startStream(updatedConstraints);
    }
}

cameraOptions.onchange = () => {
    const updatedConstraints = {
        ...constraints,
        deviceId: {
            exact: cameraOptions.value
        }
    };
    startStream(updatedConstraints, true);
}

pause.onclick = () => {
    video.pause();
    play.classList.remove('d-none');
    pause.classList.add('d-none');
}

screenshot.onclick = () => {
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
    screenshotImage.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');
    screenshotImage.classList.remove('d-none');
}
```

```css
.screenshot-image {
    width: 150px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 10px;
    background: white;
}

.display-cover {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 5% auto;
    position: relative;
}

video {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.video-options {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 30px;
}

.controls {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.controls>button {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 0 6px;
    background: transparent;
}

.controls>button:hover svg {
    color: white !important;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 400px) {
    .controls {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .controls button {
        margin: 5px 0 !important;
    }
}

.controls>button>svg {
    height: 20px;
    width: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.controls button:nth-child(1) {
    border: 2px solid #D2002E;
}

.controls button:nth-child(1) svg {
    color: #D2002E;
}

.controls button:nth-child(2) {
    border: 2px solid #008496;
}

.controls button:nth-child(2) svg {
    color: #008496;
}

.controls button:nth-child(3) {
    border: 2px solid #00B541;
}

.controls button:nth-child(3) svg {
    color: #00B541;
}

.controls>button {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 0 6px;
    background: transparent;
}

.controls>button:hover svg {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
<div class="display-cover">
    <video autoplay></video>
    <canvas class="d-none"></canvas>

    <div class="video-options">
        <select name="" id="" class="custom-select">
            <option value="">Select camera</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <img class="screenshot-image d-none" alt="">

    <div class="controls">
        <button class="btn btn-danger play" title="Play"><i data-feather="play-circle"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-info pause d-none" title="Pause"><i data-feather="pause"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success screenshot d-none" title="ScreenShot"><i data-feather="image"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In order to get multiple camera sources, I added [Droidcam](https://www.dev47apps.com). The problem is I can't change the camera source from droidcam to pc camera and vice versa. I have confirmed that `video.srcObject` has changed but still, the camera source is not changed.

[image: fail change]

Why did it happen? How to solve this? Any answer would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: your browser might ask you for permission everytime you switch cameras. A popup should appear in the top left corenr of your screen. Another app might be accessing your camera(s), therefore not allowing your browser to access one or the other.

Comment: @Oreoezi then how can google meet change camera source? It proves this task is possible from client-side even if other camera isbused by another application, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out the solution. The mistake occurred at the `constraints` object. The valid `constraint` looks like this:

```json
{
    video: {
        width: {
            min: 1280,
            ideal: 1920,
            max: 2560,
        },
        height: {
            min: 720,
            ideal: 1080,
            max: 1440
        },
        deviceId: null
    }
}
```

When selecting another input device, `constraints.video.deviceId.exact` should be updated with `cameraOptions.value` which is the selected option value (deviceId).

Additional ways that can be applied for destroying `MediaStreamTrack` before changing the camera source is with `MediaStreamTrack.stop()`.

```js
...
let currentStream = null;
...
if (currentStream) {
    currentStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
        track.stop();
    });
}
...
```

---

Full code:

```js
feather.replace();

const controls = document.querySelector('.controls');
const cameraOptions = document.querySelector('.video-options>select');
const video = document.querySelector('video');
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const screenshotImage = document.querySelector('img');
const buttons = [...controls.querySelectorAll('button')];
let streamStarted = false;
const [play, pause, screenshot] = buttons;
let currentStream = null;

const constraints = {
    video: {
        width: {
            min: 1280,
            ideal: 1920,
            max: 2560,
        },
        height: {
            min: 720,
            ideal: 1080,
            max: 1440
        },
        deviceId: null
    }
}

const getCameraSelection = () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {
        const videoDevices = devices.filter(device => device.kind === 'videoinput');
        const options = videoDevices.map(videoDevice => {
            return `<option value="${videoDevice.deviceId}">${videoDevice.label}</option>`;
        });
        cameraOptions.innerHTML = options.join('');
    });
}

const startStream = (constraints, changeMode = false) => {
    try {
        if (currentStream) {
            currentStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
                track.stop();
            });
        }
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream) => {
            if (!changeMode) getCameraSelection();
            video.srcObject = stream;
            play.classList.add('d-none');
            pause.classList.remove('d-none');
            screenshot.classList.remove('d-none');
            streamStarted = true;
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

play.onclick = () => {
    if (streamStarted) {
        video.play();
        play.classList.add('d-none');
        pause.classList.remove('d-none');
        return;
    }
    if ('mediaDevices' in navigator) {
        startStream(constraints);
    }
}

cameraOptions.onchange = () => {
    constraints.video.deviceId = {
        exact: cameraOptions.value
    };
    startStream(constraints, true);
}

pause.onclick = () => {
    video.pause();
    play.classList.remove('d-none');
    pause.classList.add('d-none');
}

screenshot.onclick = () => {
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
    screenshotImage.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');
    screenshotImage.classList.remove('d-none');
}
```

```css
.screenshot-image {
    width: 150px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 10px;
    background: white;
}

.display-cover {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 5% auto;
    position: relative;
}

video {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.video-options {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 30px;
}

.controls {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.controls>button {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 0 6px;
    background: transparent;
}

.controls>button:hover svg {
    color: white !important;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 400px) {
    .controls {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .controls button {
        margin: 5px 0 !important;
    }
}

.controls>button>svg {
    height: 20px;
    width: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.controls button:nth-child(1) {
    border: 2px solid #D2002E;
}

.controls button:nth-child(1) svg {
    color: #D2002E;
}

.controls button:nth-child(2) {
    border: 2px solid #008496;
}

.controls button:nth-child(2) svg {
    color: #008496;
}

.controls button:nth-child(3) {
    border: 2px solid #00B541;
}

.controls button:nth-child(3) svg {
    color: #00B541;
}

.controls>button {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 0 6px;
    background: transparent;
}

.controls>button:hover svg {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
<div class="display-cover">
    <video autoplay></video>
    <canvas class="d-none"></canvas>

    <div class="video-options">
        <select name="" id="" class="custom-select">
            <option value="">Select camera</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <img class="screenshot-image d-none" alt="">

    <div class="controls">
        <button class="btn btn-danger play" title="Play"><i data-feather="play-circle"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-info pause d-none" title="Pause"><i data-feather="pause"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success screenshot d-none" title="ScreenShot"><i data-feather="image"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```